# Firefox draws my picture darker than original

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have the next CSS for my header:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fullwidth {
    width: 100%;
}

.fullheight {
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 84px;
    background: #4F46C8 url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat;
}

.sidebar-container {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}

.sidebar {
    color: white;
    background-color: #0091a8;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 20px 16px 16px 16px;
}

.sidebar ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar li::before {
    content: "- ";
}

.content {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 280px;
}

.content iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    border: none;
}

.page {
    padding: 20px 16px 16px 16px;
}

.page h2 {
    color: #0091a8;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    clear: both;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar a {
    color: white;
}

.text-centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The color `#2874c2` is a color from that picture that was taken in Gimp 2. And in the image viewer the picture looks lighter than in browser. I checked a color in the browser it's `#4F46C8`.
My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>FSS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="application/javascript" src="js/app.js" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What can be wrong?
**P.S.** The picture isn't transparent.

Comment: Is it possible you have overwriting css?

Comment: @JosephCho, nope, I have only one CSS file. I have updated my post to show all CSS.

Comment: It looks like you're setting the color here: `background: #4F46C8 url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat;`. Why don't you remove the color and just reference the image.

Comment: #4F46C8 is in your css. There is no mention of the other #2874c2 color in your code. CSS works on a first-read basis. the #4f46C8 color will take precedence over the logo.